# Error when having an EntityType field where the Choices come from a ManyToMany Column

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to have an EntityType Field where the Choices come from a ManyToMany Column, but when rendering the form I get a `Warning: ReflectionProperty::setValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given` exception.

This is the Column:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\DashboardBundle\Entity\EntityType")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="entity_panel",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="panel_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $entityTypes;
```

and this is the form row:

```
->add('entityTypes', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => \App\DashboardBundle\Entity\EntityType::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
            ])
```

Error Stacktrace:

```
ErrorException:
Warning: ReflectionProperty::setValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

  at vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2829
  at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->createEntity('App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\UserDashboard', array('id' => 21, 'user_id' => 171), array('deferEagerLoad' => true, 'fetchAlias' => 'e', 'fetchMode' => array('App\DashboardBundle\Entity\UserDashboard' => array('user' => 2))))
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:271)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->getEntity(array('id' => 21, 'user_id' => 171), 'e')
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:492)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateRowData(array('id_0' => '21', 'dashboard_type_1' => 'user', 'user_id_2' => '171'), array())
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:162)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateAllData()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:152)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator->hydrateAll(object(PDOStatement), object(ResultSetMapping), array())
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:976)
  at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->executeIgnoreQueryCache(null, null)
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:922)
  at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute()
     (vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/ChoiceList/ORMQueryBuilderLoader.php:50)
  at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\ORMQueryBuilderLoader->getEntities()
     (vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/ChoiceList/DoctrineChoiceLoader.php:85)
  at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\DoctrineChoiceLoader->loadChoiceList(array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'))
     (vendor/symfony/form/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php:62)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList->getChoices()
     (vendor/symfony/form/ChoiceList/Factory/DefaultChoiceListFactory.php:53)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory->createView(object(LazyChoiceList), array(), object(Closure), array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), null, null)
     (vendor/symfony/form/ChoiceList/Factory/PropertyAccessDecorator.php:193)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\PropertyAccessDecorator->createView(object(LazyChoiceList), array(), object(Closure), array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), null, null)
     (vendor/symfony/form/ChoiceList/Factory/CachingFactoryDecorator.php:127)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\CachingFactoryDecorator->createView(object(LazyChoiceList), array(), 'name', array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), null, null)
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.php:410)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType->createChoiceListView(object(LazyChoiceList), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'label_translation_parameters' => array(), 'attr_translation_parameters' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => false, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'inherit_data' => false, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'allow_file_upload' => false, 'help_translation_parameters' => array(), 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'block_prefix' => null, 'row_attr' => array(), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => '', 'error_bubbling' => false, 'label_attr' => array(), 'compound' => false, 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'help' => null, 'help_attr' => array(), 'help_html' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'choices' => null, 'query_builder' => null, 'class' => 'App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\EntityType', 'em' => object(EntityManager), 'id_reader' => object(IdReader), 'choice_loader' => object(DoctrineChoiceLoader), 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_name' => array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), 'choice_value' => array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 'choice_attr' => null, 'preferred_choices' => array(), 'group_by' => null, 'placeholder' => null, 'choice_translation_domain' => false))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.php:185)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType->buildView(object(FormView), object(Form), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'label_translation_parameters' => array(), 'attr_translation_parameters' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => false, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'inherit_data' => false, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'allow_file_upload' => false, 'help_translation_parameters' => array(), 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'block_prefix' => null, 'row_attr' => array(), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => '', 'error_bubbling' => false, 'label_attr' => array(), 'compound' => false, 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'help' => null, 'help_attr' => array(), 'help_html' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'choices' => null, 'query_builder' => null, 'class' => 'App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\EntityType', 'em' => object(EntityManager), 'id_reader' => object(IdReader), 'choice_loader' => object(DoctrineChoiceLoader), 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_name' => array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), 'choice_value' => array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 'choice_attr' => null, 'preferred_choices' => array(), 'group_by' => null, 'placeholder' => null, 'choice_translation_domain' => false))
     (vendor/symfony/form/ResolvedFormType.php:148)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType->buildView(object(FormView), object(Form), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'label_translation_parameters' => array(), 'attr_translation_parameters' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => false, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'inherit_data' => false, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'allow_file_upload' => false, 'help_translation_parameters' => array(), 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'block_prefix' => null, 'row_attr' => array(), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => '', 'error_bubbling' => false, 'label_attr' => array(), 'compound' => false, 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'help' => null, 'help_attr' => array(), 'help_html' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'choices' => null, 'query_builder' => null, 'class' => 'App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\EntityType', 'em' => object(EntityManager), 'id_reader' => object(IdReader), 'choice_loader' => object(DoctrineChoiceLoader), 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_name' => array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), 'choice_value' => array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 'choice_attr' => null, 'preferred_choices' => array(), 'group_by' => null, 'placeholder' => null, 'choice_translation_domain' => false))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php:103)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy->buildView(object(FormView), object(Form), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'label_translation_parameters' => array(), 'attr_translation_parameters' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => false, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'inherit_data' => false, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'allow_file_upload' => false, 'help_translation_parameters' => array(), 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'block_prefix' => null, 'row_attr' => array(), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => '', 'error_bubbling' => false, 'label_attr' => array(), 'compound' => false, 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'help' => null, 'help_attr' => array(), 'help_html' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'choices' => null, 'query_builder' => null, 'class' => 'App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\EntityType', 'em' => object(EntityManager), 'id_reader' => object(IdReader), 'choice_loader' => object(DoctrineChoiceLoader), 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_name' => array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), 'choice_value' => array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 'choice_attr' => null, 'preferred_choices' => array(), 'group_by' => null, 'placeholder' => null, 'choice_translation_domain' => false))
     (vendor/symfony/form/ResolvedFormType.php:145)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType->buildView(object(FormView), object(Form), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'label_translation_parameters' => array(), 'attr_translation_parameters' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => false, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'inherit_data' => false, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'allow_file_upload' => false, 'help_translation_parameters' => array(), 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'block_prefix' => null, 'row_attr' => array(), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => '', 'error_bubbling' => false, 'label_attr' => array(), 'compound' => false, 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'help' => null, 'help_attr' => array(), 'help_html' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'choices' => null, 'query_builder' => null, 'class' => 'App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\EntityType', 'em' => object(EntityManager), 'id_reader' => object(IdReader), 'choice_loader' => object(DoctrineChoiceLoader), 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_name' => array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), 'choice_value' => array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 'choice_attr' => null, 'preferred_choices' => array(), 'group_by' => null, 'placeholder' => null, 'choice_translation_domain' => false))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/DataCollector/Proxy/ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php:103)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy->buildView(object(FormView), object(Form), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'label_translation_parameters' => array(), 'attr_translation_parameters' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => false, 'required' => true, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'inherit_data' => false, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'allow_file_upload' => false, 'help_translation_parameters' => array(), 'error_mapping' => array(), 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'block_prefix' => null, 'row_attr' => array(), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => '', 'error_bubbling' => false, 'label_attr' => array(), 'compound' => false, 'upload_max_size_message' => object(Closure), 'help' => null, 'help_attr' => array(), 'help_html' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'choices' => null, 'query_builder' => null, 'class' => 'App\\DashboardBundle\\Entity\\EntityType', 'em' => object(EntityManager), 'id_reader' => object(IdReader), 'choice_loader' => object(DoctrineChoiceLoader), 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_name' => array('Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\Type\\DoctrineType', 'createChoiceName'), 'choice_value' => array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 'choice_attr' => null, 'preferred_choices' => array(), 'group_by' => null, 'placeholder' => null, 'choice_translation_domain' => false))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:1030)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->createView(object(FormView))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:1033)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->createView()
     (src/DeveloperBundle/Controller/PanelController.php:116)
  at App\DeveloperBundle\Controller\PanelController->editPanel(object(Request), object(Panel))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:198)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:25)
```

Comment: what are the `use` in your Form ? Because it's very confusing to have entity called `EntityType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was something wrong with the Repository Class where the constructor was formed wrongly, like so:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, {WrongEntity}::class);
}
```